# JavaFX Root border same as menu border

Tags: java, css, javafx, selector

Continuing the development of my GUI, I've come across another problem. I've set a linear gradient as border for my `.root` in the CSS file, but it seems that the elements of `Menu` class somehow share the same attributes because the same linear effect has been applied to these also.
[image]
As you can see, on the bottom of the window is the effect that I told you about. Looking at the menu on the left, the effect has been applied to it also, and it's something that I do not want to happen.
This is my css file. The root is labeled as `.root`, and that menu is labeled as `.context-menu`

```
.root{//here
-fx-background-color: #2D2E32;
-fx-font-size: 12px;
-fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 4, 4;
-fx-border-color: linear-gradient(transparent, #32739B);
}

#file{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#494C58, #3E3F43);


}

#file .label{
    -fx-text-fill: #EAEAEA;

}

.context-menu{//and here
    -fx-background-color: #3E3F43;
}

#closeButton, #minimizeButton, #maximizeButton{
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#494C58, #3E3F43);
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 1, 2;
}

#closeButton:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #E46458;
}

#minimizeButton:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #80B1E0;
}

#maximizeButton:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #80E089;
}

.menu-item:hover, menu-item:focus{
    -fx-background-color: #69757A;
}

.menu{

}

.menu:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #69757A;
}

.label{
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
}

.button{
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

#submit{
    -fx-background-color: #3F494D;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 4, 4;
    -fx-text-fill: #fff;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-border-color: #32739B;
}

#submit:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #32739B;

}

.text-field{
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

#forgot{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: #818181;
}

.separator{
    -fx-background-color: #363636;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from the style class `root`:

> The .root style class is applied to the root node of the Scene
>   instance. Because all nodes in the scene graph are a descendant of the
>   root node, styles in the .root style class can be applied to any node.

Therefore if you define the border color in this class, it will be inherited by any `Node`.

You could create a new CSS class with different name

```
.rootelement {
    -fx-border-color: linear-gradient(transparent, #32739B);
    -fx-border-width: 2;
}
```

and set the root element of your layout to have this style-class

```
BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
layout.setTop(hBox);
layout.getStyleClass().add("rootelement");
```

Then you can remove the `-fx-border-color` attribute from the `root` class.

This way you can prevent any other control to inherit the border.

Comment: Man, you're awesome.Thanks so much.